# SurfaceView.setbackground() dominates my canvas

Tags: android, surfaceview

When I set the background to my surfaceview, I see what I set as the background. However, I cannot draw simple things like circles when I lock/unlock the surfaceview's canvas. All I see is the background image.

Is there something I'm missing?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to google.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-surfaceview.html

http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-v,188.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple.

```
//get surface view and surface holder

mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
surfaceHolder = mySurfaceView.getHolder();

//place surface view holder on top of the surface view
mySurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

//set pixels of the surface holder to transparent to see the color of the
//surface view background

surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```