# My Surface View is Not working

Tags: android

This is the main scenario: [KillThemAll Game](http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame8.html)

In `constructor` of my `CustomView` which extends `SurfaceView` class, I set the `background` as :

```
this.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.moon_light));
```

if I set background in one of the methods of `SurfaceHolder.Callback()`, the game and all the animations become freezed...

```
getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    gameLoopThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            createSprites();
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
           setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.moon_light));
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
        }
    });
```

why?

Comment: post your `onDraw()` implementation...

Comment: "but canvas becomes invisible" what do you mean?

Comment: You need to call `super.onDraw()` to draw a background

Comment: remove this:  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: @pskink this is the main scenario edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame8.html, how could I add a background on that Game...

Comment: Just add this line in android manifest file. 1)android:largeHeap="true" and 2) android:hardwareAccelerated="false" this line improve your memory status and help to draw your surface.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh I have added your suggested code but still not getting my job done, please help me Bro.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me you just want to draw a background. Since you have overridden `onDraw()` in your `SurfaceView` implementation to do animation, you should not rely on `View` methods to do drawing because they will conflict with your custom drawing.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null); // background replaces canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    // draw your sprites here
}
```

You just have to make sure `background` is a `Bitmap` that is bigger than the canvas size. You could also use `drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)` to scale it to the right size but it won't respect the aspect ratio.

Comment: now animations are working(slowly) but the sprites are automatically created in background see this image please  http://i.stack.imgur.com/o2gUN.png

Comment: It's because your background isn't big enough to clear the entire screen. do a `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` before drawing your background bitmap and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
this.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.moon_light));
```

with

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.moon_light);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a miskate on your src and dest rects.Try to print the values of both on the log and see whether they are correct

Comment: bro try to look at this question on how to draw bitmaps on surface views,maybe it will help

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740687/add-image-to-surface-view-in-android

Comment: thanks for calling bro, but sis I have already that and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534452/surfaceview-setbackground-dominates-my-canvas one as well, but the problem is still there...

Comment: Lol,"sis" lol.Okay I get it you want to draw a bitmap at a specific point on you canvas in the surface view right?So you use rects,but why cant you just use top and left?ie drawBitmap(bitmap,leftValue,topValue,false);?

Comment: Ok no problem, this is the main scenario http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame8.html, how could I add a background on that `Game`, and Sorry if you minded some of my words :-p

Comment: Okay you're trying to add a background to the sprite surfaceview.Im sure the call to setBackDrawble set the background,does the sprite image have a transparent background?Maybe the reason you cant see your background is that.

Comment: Okay why dont you the background to the your.main viewgroup in your layout?

Comment: Yep my `sprite` have a transparent background, I don't have idea, where is my `main viewgroup` in `layout`?

Comment: Try to add the background to the gameView view,by calling setBackgroudDrawable on it